# Unable to send data from main.js to renderer.js in Electron.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am new to electron.js. I am trying to add a functionality where a user can press cmd+f to search text on the main browser.
I was able to open the search window and capture user input and send it to main.js. Once I got the search string in the main I want to send it back to renderer.js using `mainWindow.webContents.send('highlight-text', searchTerm);` but renderer is unable to receive it.
I have also checked if the mainWindow exist at the time of sending message, and it do appears to be just fine. I am clueless why this is happening. I have attached my code below. Any help will be much appreciated.

**Main.js**

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, globalShortcut, ipcMain } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

let mainWindow;

function createWindow() {
    // Create the main browser window
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false,
            enableRemoteModule: true,
            contentSecurityPolicy: {
                directives: {
                    defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
                    scriptSrc: ["'self'"],
                    // Add other directives as needed
                },
            }
            // preload: path.join(__dirname, 'renderer.js')
        },
    });

    // Load index.html in the window
    // mainWindow.loadFile('./index.html');
    // Load Google in the main window
    mainWindow.loadURL('https://www.google.com');

    // Open the DevTools (remove this line in production)
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

    // Emitted when the window is closed
    mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
        mainWindow = null;
    });

    // Register 'Ctrl+F' or 'Cmd+F' as a global shortcut to open the find dialog
    globalShortcut.register('CmdOrCtrl+F', () => {
        const searchWindow = new BrowserWindow({
            width: 400,
            height: 200,
            webPreferences: {
                nodeIntegration: true,
                contextIsolation: false,
                enableRemoteModule: true
            },
        });
        searchWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'search.html'));
        searchWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

        // Handle closing the search window
        searchWindow.on('closed', () => {
            searchWindow = null;
        });
        // mainWindow.webContents.send('open-find');
        // console.log('open-find sent')
    });
}

// Create the main window when the app is ready
app.whenReady().then(() => {
    createWindow();
    console.log('when Ready Called')
    // Create a new window for search functionality
    ipcMain.on('open-find', () => {
        console.log('open-find listened');
    });
});

// Quit the app when all windows are closed (except on macOS)
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});

// Create a new window when the app is activated (on macOS)
app.on('activate', () => {
    if (mainWindow === null) {
        createWindow();
    }
});

// Unregister all global shortcuts when the app is about to quit
app.on('before-quit', () => {
    globalShortcut.unregisterAll();
});

// Handle IPC messages from the renderer process
ipcMain.on('perform-search', (event, searchTerm) => {
    console.log(`Performing search for: ${searchTerm}`);
    if (mainWindow && mainWindow.webContents) {
       try {
        setTimeout(() => {
            mainWindow.webContents.send('highlight-text', searchTerm);
        }, 100);
       } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
       }
    } else {
        console.log('Main window is not available...');
    }
});
```

**Renderer.js**

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

function highlight() {
    const searchInput = document.getElementById('searchInput');
    const searchTerm = searchInput.value;
    // console.log(searchTerm);
    // alert(`search text: ${searchTerm}`);
    ipcRenderer.send('perform-search', searchTerm);
}

ipcRenderer.on('highlight-text', (event, searchTerm) => {
    console.log(event);
    // Highlight text in the main window based on the search term
    console.log('highlight-text-searchTerm: ', searchTerm)
    highlightText(searchTerm);
});

function highlightText(searchTerm) {
    // Your logic to highlight the text in the main window
    const regex = new RegExp(searchTerm, 'gi');
    const body = document.body;

    // Traverse the DOM and apply the highlighting
    traverseAndHighlight(body, regex);
}

function traverseAndHighlight(node, regex) {
    console.log('traverseAndHighlight called')
    if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        const matches = node.nodeValue.match(regex);
        if (matches) {
            const span = document.createElement('span');
            span.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
            const replacedText = node.nodeValue.replace(regex, match => `<span style="background-color: yellow;">${match}</span>`);
            span.innerHTML = replacedText;
            node.parentNode.replaceChild(span, node);
        }
    } else if (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        for (const childNode of node.childNodes) {
            traverseAndHighlight(childNode, regex);
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. There is no error on the console.

Comment: In `main.js`, instead of `mainWindow.webContents.send('highlight-text', searchTerm);`, try `event.sender.send('highlight-text', searchTerm);`

Comment: @Timur It did work, but it is performing search on the same window which is the search popup window. I want it to search on the mainWindow.